# Lock/Sleep not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I wrote a simple code with a lock/sleep that proceed a request to an API and I don't understand why it's not working.

```
public class RequestHandler
{
    private static readonly Object Lock = new Object();
    public static WebResponse Request(string url)
    {
        lock(Lock)
        {
            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Multiple threads call this method at the same time.

I get as expected a call every 5 secondes but **sometimes** two threads get in there at the same time and two requests are executed spaced by less than a second.

**EDIT:**
The code that fires the requests (simplified)

```
public void Process(string url)
{
    // do some treatments
    var response = RequestHandler.Request(url);
}

public void Main()
{
    var urls = new List<string>();
    // add urls to the list...
    Parallel.ForEach(urls , Process);
}
```

Comment: can you post the code how you are using the Request method using Threads?

Comment: Is "Thread" a variable initialized earlier or "System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread" ? Try to remove the "readonly" from Lock variable declaration.

Comment: @Graffito instance of Thread has no `Sleep` method.

Comment: @Cologer: Even if it's not a good practice, you may declare somewhere:  System.Threading.Thread Thread = new  System.Threading.Thread().

Comment: @Graffito And create a extension method like `Sleep(this Thread t)`? ^_^

Comment: Are all of your requests executing without errors?

Comment: Probably your api creates a new instance for each request, meaning that there will be a different lock object for each request so this won't work. Bad design either, having a lock like this in an api.

Comment: Is this method declared in a generic type class?

Comment: I added the code that fires the requests

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with locks vs objects: You can't use a lock object, in an uninstantiated static class, because the object needs an instance in order to exist - I realise this is about as clear as mud, so I'll demonstrate:

```
// do some treatments
RequestHandler handler = new RequestHandler();
var response = handler.Request(url);
```

This way your RequestHandler is instantiated, and the Lock object can be monitored. Otherwise there is no object to lock on. I hope this helps :)

EDIT:

You also have to modify your Request method to be an instance:

```
public WebResponse Request(string url)
```

Comment: By all means downvote the question and/or answer IF you provide a comment so that the OP can learn how to better ask questions, and the people who are trying to help can learn too. Simply clicking a down arrow doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Yeah I agree... Anyway your answer didn't work out but thanks for trying

Comment: Is your Main method also running in several threads? Otherwise my code should work. Double check that you made all 3 changes I suggested.

If your Main method is also running in several threads (or even processes) it's a much harder dilemma to solve.